# Exempt code from Code Coverage in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

In Visual Studio 2010, a project is included for Code Coverage analysis. Is there any way I can exempt file(s) from this project from code coverage?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If .NET you can exclude classes/methods etc using the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116.aspx) attribute